# UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid one doublepage viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios5, uipageviewcontroller

I'm developing a page based application started from the xcode template. My problem is I would like to provide it with just one DataViewController double page sized with the spine in the middle... (documentation says I must to provide 2 DataViewControllers)

I need this is because I will have buttons over the spine...

Is it posible? Any approach?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you can override the implementation of the `UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid` as by default it is as below:

```
enum {
    UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid = 2,  // Requires two view controllers.
};
typedef NSInteger UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation; // Only pertains to 'UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl'.
```

and Make it requires only one view controller

P.S. personally would go for 3rd party library like Flipboard style